# Random ID for database users

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I need to create a table with a random generator ID for users including letters and numbers for example: FT128 instead of default auto-increment ID

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do not mix "ID for users" field value and primary key field value in the table.

Comment: Look at my response on Stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/60918318/5193536  but as you want random use uuid v4  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32965743/how-to-generate-a-uuidv4-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Get a suitably large random number (eg 6 digits of RAND()), then double check against your existing table to see if that number is already taken.  If so, try again.

If you want letters and digits, that can be achieved using BASE64():

```
SELECT MID(TO_BASE64(RAND()), 6,6);
+-----------------------------+
| MID(TO_BASE64(RAND()), 6,6) |
+-----------------------------+
| jQyMTE                      |
+-----------------------------+
```

(I picked the middle because the start and end have some repeated stuff.)

You will still need the test for dups, but it should rarely hit a dup until you have millions of "users".

Note further...  If you want only upper case, use `UPPER()`.